# maximum area of quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

In square $ABCD$, points $U, V$ are on $AB, CD$, respectively. $AV$ and $UD$ intersect at $P$ and $UC$ and $BV$ intersect at $Q$. Determine all possible ways pair of $U$ and $V$ so as to maximize the area of $PUQV$

[image]

How can I find the maximum value of $a+b$ in my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the inequality between the arithmetic mean and the harmonic mean we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
2(a+b) 
&=
2\left(\frac{xy}{x+y}+\frac{(1-x)(1-y)}{(1-x)+(1-y)}\right)
\\
&=
\frac2{\displaystyle\frac1x+\frac 1y}
+
\frac2{\displaystyle\frac1{1-x}+\frac 1{1-y}}
\\
&\le
\frac{x+y}2+\frac{(1-x)+(1-y)}2
\\
&=
1
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and equality takes place when we have both $x=y$ and $1-x=1-y$. So $x=y$ is enough.

---

**Later edit:**
Postlude after the answer was validated... I must do it for my friend Bogdan E.

There are also other geometrical arguments to maximize. For instance, note in the picture

[image: Area PUQV]

that the areas marked with the same darker color are equal. This follows from $\Delta PVD\sim\Delta PAU$, so $PV:PA=PD:PU$, so $PV\cdot PU=PA\cdot PD$, and the triangles $\Delta PAD$ and $\Delta PUV$ have the same angle in $P$, so the same area.

So instead of maximizing the area of $PUQV$, we minimize the area remainded from the square by removing twice the area of $PUQV$, for this let $P'$, $Q'$ be the projections of $P$, $Q$ on $AD$ and $BC$. Note that the area of $\Delta PAU$ is the same as the area of $\Delta P'AU$, and there are three similar triangles moved with the vertex $P$ and/or $Q$ to the sides. So we want to minimize the area of the red region in

[image: Area of four red triangles has to be minimized]

The doubled value of the red region, obtained by "flipping" the red triangles w.r.t. the sides $P'U$, $UQ'$, $VQ'$, and $P'V$, is covering first the square, and the "small rectangle in the middle" (determined by perpendiculars on the sides of the square in the intermediate points $P', Q', U, V$) is covered twice. A minimal area is obtained iff this "small rectange" degenerates, so $P',Q';P,Q$, and $U,V$ are on the same perpendiculars.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your additional efforts!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the figure:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

The area to be maximized:
$$S_{PUQV}=S_{CDU}-S_{DPV}-S_{CQV}=\frac12-\frac{y(1-a)}{2}-\frac{b(1-y)}{2}=\frac{1-b+(a+b-1)\color{red}y}{2} \tag{1}$$
subject to the constaints:
$$\begin{cases}\Delta APU\cong \Delta DPU \Rightarrow \frac xy=\frac{a}{1-a} \Rightarrow x=\frac{ay}{1-a};\\
\Delta BQU\cong \Delta CQV \Rightarrow \frac{1-x}{1-y}=\frac{1-b}{b} \Rightarrow x=1-\frac{(1-b)(1-y)}{b} \end{cases} \Rightarrow \\
\frac{ay}{1-a}=1-\frac{(1-b)(1-y)}{b} \Rightarrow \color{red}y=\frac{a+2b-2ab-1}{a+b-1}, \ \ 0<a,b\le \frac12 \tag{2}$$
Substitute $(2)$ to $(1)$:
$$S_{PUQV}=\frac{a+b-2ab}{2}=\underbrace{-\left(a-\frac12\right)\left(b-\frac12\right)}_{\le 0}+\frac14\le \frac14, \ \ \ 0<a,b\le \frac12$$
the equality occurs for $a=b=\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

WLOG we can give $A,B,C,D$ the coordinates of the unit square as shown. Let 
$U = (0,y+\delta)$ and $V = (1, y-\delta)$.

Then, for some $0 < s, t < 1$,

\begin{align}
   P &= (1-s)A + sV \\
   P &= tD + (1-t)U \\
\hline
   P &= (1-s)(0,1) + s(1,y-\delta) \\
   P &= t(1,1) + (1-t)(0, y+\delta) \\
\hline
   P &= (s, 1-s + sy - s\delta) \\
   P &= (t, t + y-ty + \delta - t\delta) \\
\hline
   s&=t=\dfrac{1-y-\delta}{2(1-y)} \\
   P &= \left(\dfrac{1-y-\delta}{2(1-y)},\dfrac{1-y^2+\delta^2}{2(1-y)}\right)
\end{align}

Similarly, for some $0 < s, t < 1$,

\begin{align}
   Q &= (1-s)B + sV \\
   Q &= tC + (1-t)U \\
\hline
   Q &= (1-s)(0,0) + s(1,y-\delta) \\
   Q &= t(1,0) + (1-t)(0, y+\delta) \\
\hline
   Q &= (s, sy - s\delta) \\
   Q &= (t, y-ty + \delta - t\delta) \\
\hline
   s&=t=\dfrac{y+\delta}{2y} \\
   Q &= \left(\dfrac{y+\delta}{2y},
              \dfrac{y^2-\delta^2}{2y}\right)
\end{align}

We want to maximize
\begin{align}
   a + b 
   &= 1-\dfrac{1-y^2+\delta^2}{2(1-y)} + \dfrac{y^2-\delta^2}{2y} \\
   &= \dfrac{y(1-y)-\delta^2}{2y(1-y)}
\end{align}

Clearly the maximum will be $\dfrac 12$ and will occur when $\delta = 0$. That is to say, the maximum will occur when $U$ and $V$ have the same $y$-coordinate.